# I need some alias for the $ to JQ in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to use JQ instead of using $ for my jquery code.

For example my current code in Jquery is:

```
  $('.addbutton').click(function () {
      if ($('#ddlList option:selected').val() != null) {
         //Do something
      } 
  });
```

and I want it to work as:

```
JQ('.addbutton').click(function () {
      if (JQ('#ddlList option:selected').val() != null) {
         //Do something
      } 
  });
```

Is it possible? how I can achieve this thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) version if you want - If you have another library which also used `$` to refer the core library

```
var JQ = jQuery.noConflict()
```

If you want a simple alias and is not worried about any other libraries then you can simple use

```
var JQ = jQuery;
```

---

Add this after jQuery library is included

```
<script src=".../jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var JQ = jQuery.noConflict()
</script>
```

Comment: Where to add this statement? In every page where I want to use jquery?

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya just after the jQuery library is included

Comment: @AnupPJohny Do we use $ and JQ both in <Script> tag on same page?

Comment: if you use `noConflict` the `$` will no longer refer to jQuery so you won't be able to refer to jQuery using `$`

Answer (score 3):

Use noConflict()

```
var JQ = jQuery.noConflict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`noConflict` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) with a `true` parameter. That will restore everything in the global scope as it was before jQuery was loaded, and return a reference to the `jQuery` object. As long as you choose a unique name for the identifier that you want to use, jQuery won't conflict with anything:

```
var JQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

To use jQuery with any other library, do it in this order to make it free of conflicts:

```
1. Include your other library.
2. Include jQuery.
3. Use the code above.
```